# Multi-language app -> Angular-gettext: how to update po files?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-angular-gettext

I am building an angular app, with internationalization using angular-gettext.
I would like to know how to better automate the workflow when updating the translation files.

Currently it is the following:
- running "grunt" (generation of pot file + translation files)
- opening all "po" files in poedit
- in poedit, update po file with the new "pot" file
- update translations in poedit & save
- run grunt again

Is there a way to have something better? 
Like, is it possible to apply the pot file to all "po" files using a grunt command?

Here is my gruntfile currently. 
Thanks a lot

```
module.exports = function(grunt) 
{
    grunt.initConfig({
          nggettext_extract: {
            pot: {
              files: {
                'po/template.pot': ['www/app/**/*.html']
              }
            },
          },
          nggettext_compile: {
            all: {
              options: {
                module: 'app'
              },
              files: {
                'www/resources/translations.js': ['po/*.po']
              }
            },
          }
        });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-angular-gettext');

    // Default task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['nggettext_extract', 'nggettext_compile']);
}
```

Comment: I too am trying to find a way to do this. A similar implementation i used once with asp.net mvc did the job of adding blank translations to the po files (from the pot file) for me. Its terribly tedious otherwise

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a way to do this!

We wrote grunt tasks to call command line [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) utilities. They are also available for windows [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gettext.htm).

Basically you need to call `msgmerge` with the po file and the pot file to update it. See the [online documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#msgmerge-Invocation) for `msgmerge` to see what you may need. It's pretty slick once you get it going.

Answer (score 0):

poedit doesn't have a command line argument to execute the "Update from pot" file feature. So I don't think it will be possible with it.